# Logistic regression classifier training count

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, computer-vision, mahout, logistic-regression

I want train a gender classifier but confused with some problem..

There are about 100,000 labeled dataset (25,000 male . 75,000 female). 
I will devide this dataset into local-train(60%) and local-test(40%)

```
List<LabeledPoint> males = getMales(); // <-- 25,000
List<LabeledPoint> females = getFemales(); // <-- 75,000

List<LabeledPoint> local = males.addAll(females); // <-- union
List[] splits = randomSplit(local, new double[] {0.6, 0.4});
List trainingData = splits[0];
List testData = splits[1];
LogisticRegressionModel model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
  .setNumClasses(10)
  .run(trainingData);
List<LabeledPoint> predictedList = model.predict(testData);

for(LabeledPoint predict : predictedList){
    if(predict.label() =="f" && predict.predictLabel()!="f"){
        fErrorCount ++;
    }
    if(predict.label() =="m" && predict.predictLabel()!="m"){
        mErrorCount ++;
    }
}
```

The prediction result for local-test data was

```
#1 (all number is based on item count)
Total prediction :36152 , error : 6619, error ratio 0.18% 
F :27747.0 , error : 2916.0, error ratio 0.10% 
M :8405.0 , error : 3703.0, error ratio 0.44%
```

As you can see predicting for female is very good, but for male is too poor.
I expected same error ratio for both of female and male.
This classifier seems good for female targeting but useless for male targeting.

So I did a pre-sampled to balance female and male are equal.
now I got 50,000 labeled dataset (25,000 male, 25,000 female)

```
List<LabeledPoint> males = getMales(); // <-- 25,000
List<LabeledPoint> females = getfemales().sublist(0,25000); // <-- hard resized.
// from here is same.
```

the prediction result was

```
#2
Total prediciton :16814 , error : 4369 - 0.259842987986202% 
F :8407.0 , error : 2225.0 - 0.2646604020459141% 
M :8407.0 , error : 2144.0 - 0.25502557392648983%
```

Online unlabeled data what model should predict this in production, may tend to female ratio is larger than male(like #1, 75:25), but this ratio could be changed something like (f:m=30:70), (f:m=80:20) in future.

In that case

1. how do I build a most adoptable model?
2. there is no way to build a model which guarantee stable error ratio for both female, male.
3. there is no way to build a model which guarantee stable error ratio even female male ratio changed?
4. is try #2 make nonesense?

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: (1) What is your metric for how adoptable a model is?  Who is adopting the model, and for what purposes?  (2a) What is your definition of stability?  (2b) Why is stability important?  (3) That depends very much on the model type you've chosen.

Comment: I am sorry for the poor content. edited some.

Comment: (1) What is your metric for how adoptable a model is? ==> [I have no specific metric for model choose, but just seeing error ratio. ] Who is adopting the model, and for what purposes? ==> [ I will choose the model manually, to classify new sign up user gender classification ] (2a) What is your definition of stability? ==> [ I am afraid that if the difference between local data gender ratio and online user gender ratio could make problem.] (2b) Why is stability important? ==> [ because I don't know the real world gender, real world gender ratio  for the new signing up users]

Comment: I'm afraid that we really can't help you along until you have a well-defined problem.  If we don't know what defines success for this effort, we can't readily drive towards it.

Comment: thank you for the concern. btw could you please give some basic advice? it is my first ml development. and not much background knowledge have.

Comment: Why #1 result's male error ratio is such large?

Comment: We can't tell without a good subset of the data.  It's possible that the two sets of data overlap enough that any training algorithm will have great troubles to discriminate between the two sets.  As I keep saying, we need more direction from you to help solve the problem.  StackOverflow is a site for specific programming problems.  It is not a site for tutoring in design considerations.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is less about ratios and more about diagnosing whether your model suffers from high bias (underfitting) or high variance (overfitting).

**For your first run**:

Your male:female ratio was 1:3, with 25,000 labelled observations for males and 75,000 labelled observations for females.

Seems like your algorithm had high error for males, for your test split (40%). Find out what your error is for your training split run (60%). Once you get this, proceed as follows:

**Case 1** (likely): If your training set error for males is significantly **lower** than it is for your test run (which I suspect is the case), your model suffers from high variance (**overfitting**). In other words, your model fits the training data well for males, but fails to generalize for new examples (test data). One way to fix this is to simply add more data. Which I assume may be tough, since you only have 25,000 male examples. Another way to fix this is via **regularization**. You can see a bit more about this [here](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/07_Regularization.html). In a nutshell, regularization penalizes your cost function for having thetas (parameters) that are too high. Very high theta values tend to result in overfitting.

**Case 2:** If your training set error for males is also **high** (near the same level as the test run error), you most likely have a high bias (underfitting) problem. One way to fix this so to increase the complexity in your model. Perhaps, add more features, or make your model a higher order polynomial function than what it currently is. But be careful, you don't want your female classification to be overfitted as a result of this.

**Comments about your second run:**
Making the ratio 50:50 by *decreasing* the female observations from 75,000 to 25,000 will seldom make a positive difference. In fact, it can even be detrimental, as you experienced. Playing with ratios, in this case, is not the answer. Once again, diagnose whether your model suffers from high variance or high bias, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Really appreciate for the answer. It seems males has vary high bias. I have to seek another solution. :) thanks @Nikhil Bhaskar

Comment: No worries Jihun. Please upvote if my answer helped :) I hope you find a solution to get low male errors

Comment: I found male generally distributed too many apps. on the other hands females tend to focus the top most famous apps. So I leave logisticregression and started to use every app's female/male install ratio data. and Finally got under 20% error ratio both male and female. thanks.